# how can i omit the number/0 in the result in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

```
sqlite3  test.db
create table data(num1 float,num2 float);
insert into data values(1.2,3.4);
insert into data values(4,0);
insert into data values(2,5);
insert into data values(3,0);
insert into data values(5.2,3);

sqlite> select num1/num2  from data  order by num1/num2 asc;
```

0.352941176470588
0.4
1.73333333333333

There are five lines in the output ,two blank lines ,how can i omit the  number/0  in the result,i want only three lines as my result

Comment: Just add where num2 <> 0 to the select query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter out records from the result, use a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT num1 / num2
FROM data
WHERE num2 <> 0
ORDER BY 1
```